# Unable to Run AWS CLI: "ImportError: cannot import name shlex_quote"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm getting the following error when I tried running AWS CLI. I've tried installing six, but it still didn't work.

Can someone advise me what's wrong?

I have never managed to run AWS CLI on this computer before.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 23, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 19, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 49, in main
    driver = create_clidriver()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 58, in create_clidriver
    event_hooks=emitter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/awscli/plugin.py", line 44, in load_plugins
    modules = _import_plugins(plugin_mapping)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/awscli/plugin.py", line 61, in _import_plugins
    module = __import__(path, fromlist=[module])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/awscli/handlers.py", line 61, in <module>
    from awscli.customizations.opsworks import initialize as opsworks_init
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/awscli/customizations/opsworks.py", line 24, in <module>
    from six.moves import shlex_quote
ImportError: cannot import name shlex_quote
```

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1051

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try reinstalling six via pip uninstall/pip install. It worked for me.

Answer (score 25):

AWSCLI 1.6.7 is broken. (I am on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS)

```
sudo pip install awscli==1.6.6
```

Comment: Just confirmed this problem on OS X 10.10.1. KTR's solution works.

Comment: Fixed issue on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS for me

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me: OSX 10.14.1 (Mojave)

Answer (score 13):

The release of 1.6.7 had an issue with the minimum version required of the six package.  This issue has been resolved and upgrading to 1.6.8 via `pip install --upgrade awscli` will fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You need six version > 1.8.0.

`$ pip install six==1.8.0`

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalling aws-cli from bundle worked for me:

```
$ curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
$ unzip awscli-bundle.zip
$ sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
$
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.299 Python/2.7.15+ Linux/4.15.0-1056-aws botocore/1.13.35
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below lines to ~/.bash_profile:

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

For MAC users

Answer (score 0):

I had to update Python
On FreeBSD I ran.
`pkg update`
`pkg upgrade`
Then I was able to run AWS
`aws --version`

> aws-cli/1.11.74 Python/2.7.13 FreeBSD/11.0-CURRENT botocore/1.5.37

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the anaconda bin from my $PATH in my .bashrc.

```
/home/<user>/anaconda2/bin/
```

Then when it started picking up from /usr/bin it worked.